# How to query who shares port 80 on Windows?

Tags: windows

Windows can share ports. For example IIS and WinRM share port 80. Is there any way to query this information?

Comment: `netstat` can query this information, so there should be a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

netsh does the job

```
netsh http show servicestate verbose=no
```

This will list all endpoints registerd in httpsys, all entries that starts from  is actually sharing port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Exacly `nmap` program can examinate what application listen on what port, he have rules definition for each application and this program checks who program rule is working on this port (by sending, receiving data and analyze this).

Answer (score 0):

`netstat -ab`

I'm not aware of a programmatic way (and you did not specify a programming language